# What is the value group of $\overline {\Bbb{Q}_p}$ and $ \Bbb{C}_p$ ? And are they discrete?

Tags: field-theory, p-adic-number-theory

What is the value group of $\overline {\Bbb{Q}_p}$ and $ \Bbb{C}_p$ ?
And are they discrete?

For finite extension of $ \Bbb{Q}_p$, there are known results for extension of valuations, but what about infinite case ? I know $ \Bbb{C}_p$'s value group is not discrete one, but I want to see what is exactly the value group, what is $｜ \Bbb{C}_p｜$ as a set.

Thank you in advance.

P.S.

Zerox gave me **｜$\Bbb{C}_p$｜＝{$p^a$｜$a∈\Bbb{Q}$}$∪${$0$}**(Thank you so much).
Could anyone give reference for this result or self-contained proof here ?

Comment: If I remembered correctly, the value groups of $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p$ and $\Bbb{C}_p$ are the same as the rational powers of $p$ (which is not a discrete group).

Comment: Thank you! You mean, ｜$\Bbb{C}_p$｜＝{$p^a｜a∈\Bbb{Q}$}$∪{0}? Value group does not change under taking completion, so I only need to find value group of one of titled two fields.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Once you know that $|\sigma(a)|= |a|$ for any $\sigma\in Aut(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p/\Bbb{Q}_p)$ then it is clear that $|a| = |f(0)|^{1/\deg(f)}$ where $f\in \Bbb{Q}_p[x]$ is $a$'s minimal polynomial, so that $|a|\in p^\Bbb{Q}\cup 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value group $\Gamma$ of an algebraically closed valued field $(K,v)$ is always divisible: let $\gamma=v(x)\in \Gamma$; then for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $x$ has an $n$th root $y\in K$, so $\gamma=v(y^n)=nv(y)$ is $n$-divisible.

More precisely, the value group of the algebraic closure of some valued field is always the divisible hull of the value group. This should be done in any book about valuations, I'm pretty sure it is in the book by Efrat.

In the case of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ and $\mathbb{C}_p$, the value group is $\mathbb{Q}$.